# Listen to mousemove only after document loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use a script called Socialite in my Wordpress site to make social share buttons appear only after the user has moved his/her mouse AND the document already loaded.

I can't get it to work together. My current script, that does work, is:

```
jQuery(document).one("mousemove", function() {
  var social_container = jQuery('.social_buttons');
  Socialite.load(social_container);
});
```

But how do I connect the document load part?

Thanks

Comment: Enclose your code within `jQuery(document).ready(function(){..all code goes here...})`

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put your code into

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){/* your code goes here*/});
```

?

Comment: Thought I tried before, but maybe I missed something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have a small typo in the first line

```
jQuery(document).one("mousemove", function() {
```

You're calling `.one("mous...` 
It should be `.on("mous...`

Next considerations is that the document ready statement below will happen before images etc have loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // your code goes here.....
});
```

using a window load statement like below waits until everything i.e.images have loaded in full

```
$(window).load(function(){
 // code here.....
});
```

I'm not sure what would suit your needs best as I have no experience with Socialite but hopefully this will give you the answers you need.

Comment: Thanks Goddak, the window vs document was indeed a consideration. I don't think I have a typo there. This is the method that you use when you want an event to only be listened to once, as opposed to every time.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Sorry @Ilan, you're right, just assumed you would want to run every time the mouse moved.